# Unique count list of products, skip blanks, skip blacklist, skip numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of products in a specific column. This column contains blanks, however all names are unique. This list is in sheet 2. I keep track of sales in sheet 1, each sale is being added below previous sale. Each sale is a range of cells eg A1:F6 containing information such as: Bill no, quantity, price per product, total price etc. Product name would be in column D. Column D additionaly contains prices and pay methods such as VISA, CASH or even blanks.

[image]

I was trying to create statistic tracker for sold products by listing what was sold and how many times using either of lists, but I can't seem to avoid listing unnecesary info from above list.

<strike>I've tried formula:</strike>

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($K$53:K53, $D$1:$D$1000)=0)*($D$1:$D$1000<>""&"<>0")), $D$1:$D$1000)
```

But not only it won't go beyond empty spaces but I can't seem to figure out how could I add black list of words or numbers to it.
Would anyone had an idea of what kind of macro or formula I could use for that even if I would add another table which would be used as blacklist?

```
=LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($K$53:K53, $D$1:$D$1000)=0)*($D$1:$D$1000<>""&"<>0"&<>$Z$10:$Z$20)), $D$1:$D$1000)
```

I've tried variations of such formula but can't get this to work...

Thank you for help.

I've managed to work my way around my messed up design etc and found best solution to handle sales / refunds with macro while it is initially engaged / posted, however I can't get multiple IF's to work properly - noob here please have mercy.

```
' This handles refund: bottle
If Range("K2").Value < "0" And IsNumeric(Range("K2")) = True And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K2").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

' This handles refund: glass
ElseIf Range("K3").Value < "0" And IsNumeric(Range("K3")) = True And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K3").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

' This handles refund: portion
ElseIf Range("K4").Value < "0" And IsNumeric(Range("K4")) = True And Range("K3").Value = "0" And Range("K2").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K4").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

' This handles sale: bottle
ElseIf Range("K2").Value > "0" And IsNumeric(Range("K2")) = True And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K2").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

' This handles sale: glass
ElseIf Range("K3").Value > "0" And IsNumeric(Range("K3")) = True And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K3").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

' This handles sale: portion
ElseIf Range("K4").Value > "0" And IsNumeric(Range("K4")) = True And Range("K3").Value = "0" And Range("K2").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K4").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

Else: MsgBox "You cannot add drinks with food. B: quantity as number only"
End If
```

Kindly asking for help. This array seem to work...but it doesn't stop - it still executes parts of the code :(

Comment: The format of this data is working against you for what you're attempting to accomplish. If you're able to reformat the data before counting you could make your task a lot easier. For example, you could get rid of all rows which don't have a product in column D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the sum of the quantity of the of each product sold by using a combination of sumif, index/match and offset.

[image]

**Find the first match for the 1st product in the list:**

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H$2,$D:$D,0),1)
```

**Quantity for the 1st match of the 1st product in the list:**

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(D:D,MATCH($H$2,D:D,0),1),1,-1)
```

**Find the 1st match of the last product in the list:**

```
=INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H$3,$D:$D,0),1)
```

**Quantity for the 1st match of the last product in the list:**

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H$3,$D:$D,0),1),1,-1)
```

**Put them together to build your ranges and add the sum criteria:**

```
=SUMIF($D:$D,$H2,OFFSET(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H$2,$D:$D,0),1),0,-1):OFFSET(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H$3,$D:$D,0),1),0,-1))
```

Comment: Jenn, while I understand this couldn't be dumber of me not think of offset I honestly very much appreciate you pointing this out to me as this is spot on to what I needed. Thanks to you I'll be able to create statistic feedback based on sales purchases etc and I thank you for your time looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to reformat your data into a tabular form. Essentially it means that each row would be a sale and all attributes for that sale will be column headers. This will make it much easier to analyze your data.

If you want to keep your current data formatting method, first let me summarize my understanding of your question - you want to count the number of times a product, the name for which appears in a list on a second sheet, appears in col D (looks to be types of wine). For this, I suggest you read up on SUMPRODUCT.
For example, say you want to count the number of times the Pablo Neruda comes up-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((D:D)="Pablo Neruda Cabernet Savignon"))
```

The '--' turns the array function of Trues and Falses into 1s and 0s that can be counted.
-Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best I came up with was to handle tracking sales / refunds / cxl at the very initial stage of such actions being posted - this way it gave me chance to track even more than I initialy expected. I will share example file as soon as I'll come back from holidays so that all interested could understand better what I needed.

My solution as below - I had to separate checking for IsNumeric as it was going through text ... :

```
    If Not IsNumeric(Range("K2")) Or Not IsNumeric(Range("K3")) Or Not IsNumeric(Range("K4")) Then
MsgBox ("Bottle, Glass or Portion as number only!")
GoTo final
End If

If MsgBox("Confirm action.", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

' This handles refund: bottle
If Range("K2").Value < "0" And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K2").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
' This handles refund: glass
ElseIf Range("K3").Value < "0" And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K3").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
' This handles refund: portion
ElseIf Range("K4").Value < "0" And Range("K3").Value = "0" And Range("K2").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K4").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "G").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
' This handles sale: bottle
ElseIf Range("K2").Value > "0" And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K2").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
' This handles sale: glass
ElseIf Range("K3").Value > "0" And Range("K4").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K3").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd
' This handles sale: portion
ElseIf Range("K4").Value > "0" And Range("K3").Value = "0" And Range("K2").Value = "0" Then
rowNum = Range("I1").Value
copySheet.Range("K4").Copy
calcSheet.Cells(rowNum, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd

Else: MsgBox "You cannot add drinks with food!"
GoTo final
End If
```